# Rav Nissan Kaplan - biography

Tags: rabbis, yeshiva-school, biography, mir

Rav Nissan Kaplan <strike>is one of the Rashei Yeshiva at the Mir in Jerusalem,</strike> teaches English-speaking students in Walmark (וולמארק), which is one of the two *batei midrash* in the Bet Yeshaya building, established in 2005. <strike>Prior to this, I think that he was mashgiach ruchani for the English-speaking *avreichim*</strike>. My information to this effect is coming largely from the brief mention that is made to him on Wikipedia's [Hebrew page](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%91%D7%AA_%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A8#.D7.91.D7.A0.D7.99.D7.99.D7.A0.D7.99_.D7.94.D7.99.D7.A9.D7.99.D7.91.D7.94) for the Mir Yeshiva in Jerusalem, and might not be correct.

I am a long-time fan of Rav Kaplan's mussar and halakha schmuessen (which are available online [here](http://ravkaplan.dafyomireview.com/)), and would like to know more about who he is. Specifically, I have the following two questions:

- In a number of his schmuessen, Rav Kaplan makes reference to his father, who appears (from what Rav Kaplan says) to have been close to Rav Shach. Does anybody know the identity of Rav Kaplan's father? Is he a Rosh Yeshiva somewhere? Rav Kaplan himself learnt at Ponevezh, if that helps.
- In one of his schmuessen ([this one](http://ravkaplan.dafyomireview.com/aud/5773-Mussar/004-not_to_become_immuned.mp3), starting just after the 9:10 mark), Rav Kaplan refers to a camp that his father runs, called Mevakshei HaShem. I would very much like to know more information about this camp: where it runs, at what level it runs (it certainly sounds very prestigious) and whether or not there are other camps like it.

I am, as I say, a big fan of Rav Kaplan's classes. It would help me immeasurably to know a little bit more about who he actually is and who his father is. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suppose you don't live in Eretz Yisrael otherwise you could just ask him...Maybe try finding an old or current talmid to get the information...

Comment: Rav Nissin Kaplan is NOT a Rosh Yeshiva in the Mir, although he is one of the Rebbeim there. The Rosh Yeshivas in the Mir are Rabbi Laizer Yudel Finkel, Rav Refoel Shmuelevitz, Rav Yitzchok Ezrachi and Rav Binyamin Carlebach. Rav Nissan Kaplan was never officially a mashgiach for American Avreichim in the Mir (the Mashgiach is Rav Aharon Chodosh), but he is a known Mussar personality and does give Mussar Shiurim in for Mir students, especially for Avreichim. I learn in the Mir, I'll try to ask someone tomorrow about this information if I remember...

Comment: Thank you, @RebChaimHaQoton! I would appreciate that. (And have noted your correction in my question.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

His father is Rabbi Naftali Kaplan

big tzadik. he used to give a shiur at ohr somayach in jerusalem. lives in bayit vegan.
teaches somewhere else now. very busy and difficult to speak to. he has a fax. dont have the number though

you can try to contact Rabbi Nissan Kaplan through the email at the site. although he does not use email nor read english!. his secretary takes care of the emails.

although he (Rav Nissan) is not a rosh yeshiva or mashgiach, he is highly accessible to his talmidim or anyone else who wants to speak with him. more influential probably then many of the official roshei yeshiva

Comment: Rabbi Naftoli Kaplan is an American

Answer (score 3):

Rabbi Naftoli Kaplan lived in Baltimore and was a Rebbi in Yeshivas Ner Israel before moving to Israel. I was a talmid of his there in the 60's. While I can't recall if I ever witnessed him reading English, I assume he certainly can read English as he lived in the US. 
Kol Tuv

Comment: I attend ve'adim he oversees. There are numerous such groups across Israel and North America, thanks to Skype and road trips. Free -- donations only. And yes, he speaks English fluently, no accent. As you would expect from an American.

Also, I agree with @ray -- "big tzadik"!

Comment: yes Rabbi Naftoli can read english. when i said, he cant speak english was referring to his son.

Answer (score 2):

Rav Naftali Shlita is a Native of Chicago and definitely speaks and reads english fluently. Rav Nissan Shlita has left The Mir and is now the Rosh HaYeshiva of Yeshivas Da'as Aaron.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first answer. Great to have you learn with us!